# RSS Feed reader using Firebase Feed the Fire

Tags: firebase, rss, rss-reader

I was just going through some ready solution to grab rss feeds from urls and came across "[FeedTheFire](https://www-staging.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-25-rss-to-firebase.html)".

But the [Github link](https://github.com/firebase/feedthefire) to it is giving me 404 error.

Is this service/project still alive or they moved it somewhere else or stopped development on this?

Comment: First line in the blog post:  **UPDATE: Feed the Fire and Persona auth have been discontinued**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Feed the Fire blog](https://www-staging.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-25-rss-to-firebase.html) you linked is from the Legacy Firebase times (pre-Google). From there, it is included (as per Kato's comment):

> **UPDATE: Feed the Fire and Persona auth have been discontinued**

I've done some quick searching and found this [Feed the Fire on GitHub](https://github.com/katowulf/feedthefire) by [Kato](https://stackoverflow.com/users/394010/kato), where the last update was from May 2014 (AFAIK, still pre-Google times).

Comment: That repo is a fork from another fork from the old repo which doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @Kato What about [**firereader**](https://github.com/firebase/firereader)? Can I use this?